# Debugger not stop on breakpoints android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have latest `android studio` installed on my **Mac** and latest java run time environment, i have big problem i have started working on android lat few weeks but when i try to create the project with template given by studio like login that time debugger stop on my phone/device and bluestack too.
but when i added my some new files or create some new xml or activity on same project debugger being stop working as not stoping on breakpoints,
i have googled find some answers and applied them but didn't help, is anyone know how was this happening?

Comment: attach screenshot with code

Comment: Did you push a new debug build after making the changes?

Comment: it happen with every project not for single how can i post screenshot?